# Which pdf reader supports tab feature on single file?

Tags: pdf

I need a pdf reader software which supports tabbed reading on single file. That means, assume that my pdf file has 20 chapters. While i am reading chapter 1 in a tab, on the same time, i need to open chapter 2 (or any chapter) in another tab. Now i am using Foxit Reader. But it doesn't support this feature.
Edit:
My OS - Windows8 32 bit
And i prefer free softwares.

Comment: What OS must be supported?

Comment: And how much are you willing to pay for it?

Comment: If we don't find one, then consider using bookmarks for quick switching between chapters, or running multiple versions of the PDF reader.

Comment: @lazzy Windows8 32 bit

Comment: @Mawg I prefer free softwares

Answer (score 1):

How about Google Chrome / Chromium? Here is a local PDF that I opened in two tabs, and that I can navigate independently:

[image: Multiple tabs opened]

Other browsers may also be capable of the same, but I only tested this in Chromium.

Comment: I have tested with Chrome. But i need this feature, that is : If i right click on contents page i need an option "Open in new tab".